# Add html to same class multiple times on page

Tags: jquery, html, append

I ran into a problem with jQuery's html() function. I want to use it multiple times with the same id/class, but it only works once.

I have this jQuery code (integrated in a form and a submit function):

```
var flFrom = $('#fl-from').val();
var flTo = $('#fl-to').val();
var flFromDate = $('#fl-from-date').val();
var flToDate = $('#fl-to-date').val();
var flPassengers = $('#fl-passengers').val();

$('#flight-from').html(flFrom);
$('#flight-to').html(flTo);
$('#flight-from-date').html(flFromDate);
$('#flight-to-date').html(flToDate);
$('#flight-passengers').html(flPassengers);
```

And this is the corresponding html

```
<span id="flight-from"></span>
<span id="flight-to"></span>
<span id="flight-from-date"></span>
<span id="flight-to-date"></span>
<span id="flight-passengers"></span>
```

It works perfectly fine, however, I want to use multiple span's with the same id or class and fill all of them with the content of the form... so let's say I have the `#flight-from` six times on the website instead of once.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: IDs ***must*** be unique on document context. Use class instead and any transversal method to target specific elements regarding the FORM to submit. As you didn't provide enough info as all relevant HTML markup, it's quite impossible to help you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an id is always used to be only once per page... Please use classes instead.

You could do it like this:

```
<span class="flight-from"></span>
<span class="flight-from"></span>
<span class="flight-from"></span>
<span class="flight-from"></span>
<span class="flight-from"></span>
<span class="flight-from"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.flight-from').html($('#fl-from').val());

</script>
```

This fills every class named flight-from with the value from #fl-from.

Comment: Thanks! I made a very stupid mistake: I forgot to close the <span> tag, that's why it didn't work in the first place.